# How to mesure startup time of a unit test run from maven or intellij?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, junit

As expected, Junit unit tests reports the time of each test themself, 
but not of the initialization process preceding the test(s).

How to mesure this time ?

The init time, in my case of a spring-boot application, 
can be much longer than the test itself, it would thus be useful to mesure its duration to then be able to reliably improve it.

Comment: If it's spring boot test which starts up the context it's an integration and not a unit test anymore...

Comment: @khmarbaise would you mind adding any helpfull practical detail ?

Comment: Just subtract the test time from build time and the result is what you are searching for? Ah forgot something just build without any test ...

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not yet implemented. Please follow/comment or vote for the duplicate feature request already created at YouTrack in IntelliJ IDEA project: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169282
Thank you